# RS232 communication protocol Mitsubishi FX3G PLC

Tags: c#, vb6, serial-port, plc

Does anyone know the communication protocol for communication with the RS232 port of a Mitsubishi FX3G PLC?

I searched the site of Mitsubishi and Googled, but couldn't find the syntax of the commands to send to obtain the data of specific registers in the PLC.

I found the following parts of the command though:

- BR = bit read
- BW = bit write
- WR = word read
- WW = word write

I could not find though wether i should use a straight cable, or a crossed cable, and not even at which baudrate i should communicate (or other settings like data bits, stop bits, and parity)

Does anyone have any experience with RS232 communication with a FX3G PLC ?

- what is the baudrate (and other communication settings) ?
- how is the header of the command built up ?
- how is the command itself built up ?
- how is the checksum calculated ?

(It doesn't matter in which coding language or just a protocol manual)

Comment: Which language are you developing in: vb6 or c#?

Comment: probably in vb6 as i have faster results with that .. but it doesn't matter in which language the answer/example/info is given as i can read vb6/c++/c#/java/fortran/pascal/and probably some more .. and then translate it into the language which i will use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the required documentation [here](https://my.mitsubishi-automation.com/downloads_show.php?portal_id=1&doc_type=man&slang=2&sstr=FX3)

The default communication settings are a baudrate of 9600, even parity, 7 data bits, 1 stop bit, and no checksum

I changed this to a baudrate of 19200, none parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, and checksum turned on :

[image: communication parameters]

A small VB6 project :

```
'1 form with :
'    1 mscomm control : name=comFX
'    1 command button : name=cmdSend
'    1 textbox        : name=txtShow   multiline=true
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private mstrData As String
Private mblnBusy As Boolean

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With App
    Caption = .Title & " " & CStr(.Major) & "." & CStr(.Minor) & "." & CStr(.Revision)
  End With 'App
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim sngWidth As Single
  Dim sngTxtHeight As Single
  Dim sngCmdWidth As Single, sngCmdHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngCmdHeight = 315
  sngTxtHeight = ScaleHeight - sngCmdHeight
  txtShow.Move 0, 0, sngWidth, sngTxtHeight
  cmdSend.Move sngCmdWidth, sngTxtHeight, sngWidth, sngCmdHeight
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSend_Click()
  ReadReg "D8013", 7  'sec,min,hr,day,month,year,dayofweek
  ReadReg "R3310", 10 '10 data registers
End Sub

Private Sub ReadReg(strReg As String, intNr As Integer)
  Dim strCmd As String
  If NotBusy Then
    strCmd = "00FFWR0" & strReg & Right$("00" & Hex$(intNr), 2)
    strCmd = Chr$(5) & strCmd & GetSum(strCmd)
    With comFX
      If .PortOpen = False Then CommOpen
      .Output = strCmd
    End With 'comFX
    mblnBusy = True
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommOpen()
  With comFX
    If .PortOpen = True Then .PortOpen = False
    .CommPort = 1
    .Settings = "19200,N,8,1"
    .RThreshold = 1
    .PortOpen = True
  End With 'comFX
End Sub

Private Function NotBusy() As Boolean
  Dim lngTimeout As Long
  Dim blnResult As Boolean
  blnResult = True
  lngTimeout = GetTickCount + 1000 'timeout after being busy for 1 second
  Do While mblnBusy
    DoEvents
    If GetTickCount > lngTimeout Then
      blnResult = False
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop
  NotBusy = blnResult
End Function

Private Sub comFX_OnComm()
  Dim strInput As String
  Select Case comFX.CommEvent
    Case comEvReceive
      strInput = comFX.Input
      mstrData = mstrData & strInput
      ProcessData
  End Select
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessData()
  'answer : ^02 00FF <data registers 4 characters per reg> ^03
  Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
  Dim strHead As String, strSum As String
  Dim strEnd As String
  Dim strData As String
  lngStart = InStr(mstrData, Chr$(2))
  If lngStart > 0 Then
    strEnd = Chr$(3)
    lngEnd = InStr(lngStart, mstrData, strEnd)
    If lngEnd > 0 Then
      strHead = Mid$(mstrData, lngStart + 1, 4)
      If strHead = "00FF" Then
        strData = Mid$(mstrData, lngStart + 1, lngEnd - lngStart)
        strSum = Mid$(mstrData, lngEnd + 1, 2)
        If CheckSum(strData, strSum) Then
          mstrData = Mid$(mstrData, lngEnd + 3)
          ShowData Mid$(strData, 5, Len(strData) - 5)
          mblnBusy = False
        End If
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Function CheckSum(strData As String, strSum As String) As Boolean
  If strSum = GetSum(strData) Then
    CheckSum = True
  Else
    CheckSum = False
  End If
End Function

Private Function GetSum(strCmd As String) As String
  Dim intChar As Integer
  Dim lngSum As Long
  lngSum = 0
  For intChar = 1 To Len(strCmd)
    lngSum = lngSum + Asc(Mid$(strCmd, intChar, 1))
  Next intChar
  GetSum = Right$("00" + Hex$(lngSum), 2)
End Function

Private Sub ShowData(strData As String)
  txtShow.SelText = strData & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Be careful not to send the commands too fast. Once per plc cycle (100 ms in my case) seems to be the limit.

This code is in VB6, but the same could be applied in C# or any other languages.
If you want me to make an example in C#, please contact me.

Answer (score 4):

See if this manual doesn't help you, http://www.automationsystemsandcontrols.net.au/PDF%27s%20Mitsubishi/Manuals/FPLC/FX%20SERIES%20USER%27S%20MANUAL%20-%20Data%20Communication%20Edition.pdf. A list of manuals is also available at http://www.automationsystemsandcontrols.net.au/Technical%20Mitsubishi.html.

Comment: thanks! yesterday i found a whole list of manuals at https://my.mitsubishi-automation.com/downloads_show.php?portal_id=1&doc_type=man&slang=2&sstr=FX3 .... the FX1S/FX1N/FX2N(C)/FX3U Communications Manual contained the protocol that i need :)